# MultipartFormData wrapped inside object

Tags: java, rest, multipart

I have a rest endpoint:

```
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Path("/{test}/test")
@POST
public Response add(@Valid @MultipartForm CustomObject object, @PathParam("test") String test);
```

The CustomObject class:

```
public abstract class CustomObject {

    @FormParam("name")
    private String name;

    @FormParam("folder")
    @PartType("application/json")
    private CustomFolder folder;

    ......
}
```

And i can post a multipart file with all the above information.

Now i want to also pass a ConnectionParameter object which will contain some info.

So i created a CustomObjectWrapper which contains:

```
public class CustomObjectWrapper {

    @FormParam("document")
    @PartType("application/json")
    private CustomObject document;

    @FormParam("parameter")
    @PartType("application/json")
    private ConnectionParameter parameter;

    ......
}
```

and the endpoint looks like this:

```
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Path("/{test}/test")
@POST
public Response add(@Valid @MultipartForm CustomObjectWrapper object, 
@PathParam("test") String test);
```

But when i try to test it from PostMan i dont know how to set the file inside the text property.

The ConnectionParameter cant be embedded inside CustomObject because their dont have something in common.

How should i proceed?

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOjzq.png)

You can choose from-data option and choose the file. I have attached the screenshot, please let me know it helps or not.

Comment: This is for the first case what for the second case which is my actual problem? Also i would like to know if my approach is correct.